# How to resize image just before saving it the folder so that it will have fixed height in bootstrap 4 card using flask?

Tags: python, css, bootstrap-4

I have bootstrap 4 cards and I'm using **card-img-top** to make images responsive. The only issue is the images are of variable sizes and I input these images using AJAX to the backend.
I want to reduce the size of the image(height and width) so that it will be responsive as well as of fixed length.

below is my upload view to which im calling as soon as i submit the form.

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def upload():
if 'photos[]' in request.files:
  photos = request.files.getlist('photos[]')
  photo = photos[0]

  label = request.form["label"]
  email = request.form["email"]

  img_formate = "." + str(photo.filename).split(".")[-1] 
  image = label + img_formate

  #i just want to resize image to width = 360 px and height to 300px
  photo.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], image))

  return " "
```

Comment: Use the python pillow package. Here is what you are looking for [resize](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.resize).

Comment: will Image.resize(photo,(360,300)) work? coz I tried one of the methods before and that required to save the image before then read it with imread. and after that too it wasn't working.

Comment: I tried to use the resize method from PIL in colab it is working fine but for that to work either need to save image or use  URL to get the image and resize it.. right?

Comment: yes, what is the issue you have now?

Comment: it worked! but what if an image is of less size (height and width wise) then how to make it to fixed height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks, @srikanth Chekuri for helping me.

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def upload():
if 'photos[]' in request.files:
  photos = request.files.getlist('photos[]')
  photo = photos[0]

  label = request.form["label"]
  email = request.form["email"]

  img_formate = "." + str(photo.filename).split(".")[-1] 
  image = label + img_formate

  #this worked for me.
  photo = Image.open(photo)
  photo = photo.resize((400,300))

  photo.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], image))

return " "
```